# Customizing JSON response with additional index keys

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I use the `response()` helper on HTTP Response as documented. The straightforward use:

```
response()->json(
    $this->response,
    $this->status
)->withHeaders([]);
```

This will output:

```
{
    "key" : "desired response"
}
```

However, I wanted to add a key on the response:

```
$return['message'] = 'Request successful';
$return['data'] = response()->json(
    $this->response,
    $this->status
)->withHeaders([]);
```

But the response resulted to:

```
{
  "message": "Request successful",
  "data": {
    "headers": {},
    "original": {
      "key" : "desired response"
    },
    "exception": null
  }
}
```

There are extra keys on the response: `headers`, `original` & `exception`. How can I get rid of that in order to achieve this desired format:

```
 {
    "message": "Request successful",
    "data": {
        "key" : "desired response"
    }
 }
```

Comment: why you don't use return  response()->json()...?

Comment: @MortaddaJafar- I am using that, as you can see on my post, its just that whenever I wanted to add custom keys it doesn't return my intended response and it adds keys (exception, headers, original) which I don't need.

Comment: yes, you can do this just by using return response()->json(YOUR DATA,,)..

Answer (score 1):

You can you Laravel [Provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/providers)

```
php artisan make:provider ResponseMacroServiceProvider

<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Response;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ResponseMacroServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Bootrap the application service
     */
    public function boot() {
        Response::macro('success', function ($headers, $originals) {
            return Response::json([
                'message' => "Request successful",
                'data'   => [
                    'headers' => $headers,
                    'original' => $originals,
                ],
                'error' => [
                    'code' => 0 ,
                    'message' => []
                ]
            ]);
        });


        Response::macro('error', function ($message, $status = 400) {
            if(is_array($message))
                $message_repsonse = $message;
            else
                $message_repsonse = [$message];
            return Response::json([
                'message' => "Request failed",
                'data' => [
                    'headers' => null,
                    'original' => null,
                ]
                'error' => [
                    'code' => $status,
                    'message' => $message_repsonse
                ]
            ]);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register application service
     * @override
     */
    public function register() {

    }

}
```

Edit your `config/app.php`

```
/*
 * Application Service Providers...
*/
App\Providers\ResponseMacroServiceProvider::class,
```

And try to handle at your `Controller`

```
$headers = 'Your header';
$originals = Your_Model::find(1);

return response()->success($headers, $originals);

return response()->error($validator->errors()->all(), 300);
```

Comment: Nope, I am trying to eliminate headers and originals. Based on your suggestion, it is including that. And I am using Lumen, seems that provider is not available in `make:` of artisan.

Answer (score 0):

you  can achieve this by using this code:

```
 $return =[] ;
 $return['message'] = 'Request successful'; // your message
 $return['data'] =  $this->response;  // your data
 return response()->json(     // return json
    $return,  // your data here 
    $this->status    // status here
);
```